# Difference between Sign-extends the immediate vs Zero-extends the immediate

Tags: assembly, mips

To my understanding:

Zero-extends the immediate- will pad the immediate with zeros from left, so:

```
   ori $t1, $0, 0xF
```

result:

```
    0x0000000F
```

Sign-extends the immediate - will pad the immediate with the most significant bit, so:

```
    addi $t1, $0, 0xF
```

result:

```
   0xFFFFFFFF
```

I am obviously wrong, but why?

Comment: Because you need to consider the size of the immediate, which is 16 bits in mips (I assume you use mips, you forgot to mention...) Thus your immediate is actually `0x000F` and so the MSB is zero.

Comment: Oh ok. i guess i am looking for an example where sign extension can cause a problem.

Comment: Use a bigger immediate, e.g. `0xffff`.

Comment: @Jester can post your comment as an answer, so i can mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consider the size of the immediate, which is 16 bits in mips. Thus your immediate is actually `0x000F` and so the MSB is zero. To illustrate sign extension to negative, use a bigger immediate that has bit #15 set, such as `0xffff` which will indeed be interpreted by the cpu as `0xffffffff`.